# List of Commonly Used Comments

Tags: discussion, comments

I recently found out about [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), which is the AutoReviewComments script. It's been extremely helpful for me for when I want to comment something that I often do (like mcve). I was wondering if there is a list of commonly used comments that I could add to my extension.

If not, let's start a list on this question. Supa Mega Ducky Momo da Waffle created an answer with those that he uses. If you have any that you didn't see, add them onto his answer.

Comment: See the global Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments. And consider that less is often more: most of these cases *do not* require a comment. A downvote and/or a flag is sufficient.

Comment: @CodyGray in some cases, I agree. But mostly, I disagree. Sometimes, the person just made a mistake, or didn't know. No point in downvoting a potentially good question or answer because of a mistake

Comment: Yes, there is *every* point in downvoting a low-quality post. That's a *critical* aspect of our quality ranking system. It has nothing to do with whether the person made a mistake. Votes aren't about people.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This list certainly isn't complete, but here are the ones I use most (note: markdown is shown for easy copy-pasting):

```
This does not provide an answer to the question. You can 
[search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), 
or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand 
side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different 
question, 
[ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), 
and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: 
[Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

---

A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful 
without it: [add context around the link] 
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) 
so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then 
quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target 
page is unavailable. 
[Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

---

Please don't add "*Me too*" as an answer. It doesn't actually provide an 
answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then 
[ask](/questions/ask) it and reference this one if it will help provide 
context. If you're interested in this specific question, you can
[upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment] 
(/help/privileges/comment), or start a 
[bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation] 
(/help/whats-reputation).
```

Low Quality Posts "recommend deletion" canned comments:

```
This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient 
[reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able 
to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); 
instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker] 
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173).

---

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient 
[reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be 
able to [vote up questions and answers] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

---

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, 
you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more 
attention to this question once you have enough [reputation] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

---

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this 
question if it helps provide context.

---

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential 
parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers 
can become invalid if the linked page changes.
```

Comment: If possible, could you put those in the answer without the markdown applied (like with the ** for bold) so that I can copy and paste from there.

Comment: @AniketG right now I'm editing to add LQP canned comments. After that I can put in the markdown instead of rendered output.

Comment: What's the point of leaving one of the close reasons or one of the review comments in a comment? Flag/vote to close or flag for the appropriate reason (NAA/VLQ) instead.

Comment: @BDL it takes time for questions to be closed. Leaving the close reason as a comment tells them that it may be closed and why *before* it's actually closed.

Comment: Under no circumstances should you be leaving those off-topic close reasons as *comments*. Flag/vote to close the post, and move along. If a consensus is reached, a "comment" is automatically added, in the form of a big yellow banner.

Comment: @CodyGray off-topic close reasons edited out.